# Taylor expansions to approximate multivariable functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

The way this question is phrased is confusing me more than the question itself, so I will quote it how it is written in my book: "Using Taylor's theorem, find linear and quadratic approximations to the following $f(x,y)$ for small $x,y$. Give the tangent plane function $z=p(x,y)$ whose graph is tangent to $z=f(x,y)$ at $(0,0,f(0,0))$." The functions given to approximate are

a) $\sqrt{1+2x-y}$

b) $(1+x)/(1+y)$

c) $x\cos(x-y)$

d) $\cos(x+\sqrt{\pi^2+y})$

Because of the last part of the question, I assumed that I should find the Taylor series approximation around the point $(0,0)$, but I'm not positive. Should I leave it in a general case since a point isn't specified, or is the point $(0,0)$? As far as finding the tangent plane function, would it be using the method on [this page](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/TangentPlanes.aspx)?

Comment: "small $x,y$" seems to imply that everything should be done around $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can expand any function in several variables as Taylor series (have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Taylor_series_in_several_variables)).

For example, limiting to first order  for two variables around $x=y=0$, this will give around $$f(x,y) \simeq f(0,0)+x f^{(1,0)}(0,0)+y f^{(0,1)}(0,0)+x y f^{(1,1)}(0,0)$$ which, if you think about it corresponds to the simplest bilinear model you could build for approximating the function. To reduce to the tangent plane (as shown in the link you give in the post), you would need to ignore the cross term.

The same applies if you make the development around $x=a$, $y=b$ $$f(x,y) \simeq f(a,b)+(x-a) f^{(1,0)}(a,b)+(y-b) f^{(0,1)}(a,b)+(x-a)(y-b)f^{(1,1)}(a,b)$$

Comment: When you say "ignore the cross term" for the tangent plane you mean the last term in that first formula, right?

Comment: This is correct. You can do it because not too far from the reference point $\Delta x\cdot\Delta y$ would be quite small since each of them is small.